# web scraping using python beautifulsoup but not getting the value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using this script to scrape the author information from sciencedirect articles,but I am getting none when trying to print the value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
import csv
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

with open('urls.txt') as inf:
    urls = (line.strip() for line in inf)
    for url in urls:
        site = urlopen(url)   
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site, "lxml")
        for item in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "AuthorGroups"}):
            final = item.text,url
            print final
```

In urls.txt I used these 2 urls (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009286749290520M,https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0092867495903682)

Comment: Does it scrape other fields from sciencedirect, or does it work with other links in the textfile? It could be that ScienceDirect doesn't allow scraping.

Comment: I am not able to fetch anything from scienceDirect .But when I am using this program for other journals its working.And I am getting none when trying to print the value, but can be found in 'Inspect Element'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if BeautifulSoup not returned expected value, see html response from the server.

Your request blocked because it need to set proper user-agent.

```
.....
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0'}
for url in urls:
    print url
    site = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    .....
```

Comment: When I tried by including headers its working.Thank you

Comment: you're welcome. if it solved, please mark the answer as correct.